# Unable to get setTimeout to work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

I am using jquery to slide up an down a div.

For some reason setTimeout is not working (looks like a function scope issue).

Not able to figure out what is wrong with the below code.
(both functions are inside $(document).ready(function(){ } )

```
$('.slider-thumb').click(function(){
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image_view').css('background-image',"url("+source+")");
    $('#image_view').slideDown(1000, calbck);
    initiate_timeout();

    function calbck(){}
});

function initiate_timeout(){
    var time_out = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_view').slideUp(1000, calbck);
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried alerting before the `setTimeout()` to ensure the function is being called?

Comment: -1 don't ask questions without even debugging to see if your code has blatant errors. (see comments on my answer)

Comment: still going through the learning curve.. this was way faster than debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some JS errors and scoping issues.  Why would you ever have debugging turned off when trying to troubleshoot an error?  Change your code to this:

```
$('.slider-thumb').click(function(){
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image_view').css('background-image',"url("+source+")");
    $('#image_view').slideDown(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_view').slideUp(1000);
    },2000);  // will start 2 seconds after slideDown starts (which is 1 second after it completes)
});
```

or even better, use the completion function of the first animation to set the timer:

```
$('.slider-thumb').click(function(){
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image_view').css('background-image',"url("+source+")");
    $('#image_view').slideDown(1000, setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_view').slideUp(1000);
    },1000));  // will stay open for 1 second before sliding up again
});
```

Or, even better, using jQuery's delay/queuing, you can do this:

```
$('.slider-thumb').click(function(){
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image_view').css('background-image',"url("+source+")");
    $('#image_view').slideDown(1000).delay(1000).slideUp(1000);  // delay 1 sec between effects
});
```

The calbck you were trying to pass to slideUp was not defined in the scope you were using it (inside of `initiate_timout()`).  It was private to your click handler.

jQuery probably has better ways to chain effects than using your own timer, but I see no reason why this code shouldn't work if it matches your HTML.

Note: if your background image wasn't already pre-cached, it may not be loaded right away when your slideDown starts.

Answer (score 2):

Indenting the source code shows that you indeed have some scoping issue. The calbck function is private to the click handler function, and is thus not visible to initiate_timeout function. Either make calbck a top-level function, or make initiate_timeout a function local to the click handler function.

```
$('.slider-thumb').click(function() {
    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image_view').css('background-image',"url("+source+")");
    $('#image_view').slideDown(1000, calbck);
    initiate_timeout();

    function calbck(){}
});

function initiate_timeout(){
    var time_out = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_view').slideUp(1000, calbck);
        }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. Rewrote it as jfriend00 suggested, issue is now gone. Was a scope issue like you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors? You're passing an undefined value as `calbck` to `slideUp` in the `setTimeout` function.

It works for me (with my modified organization): http://jsfiddle.net/v3cjG/1/

And when I run your exact code ( http://jsfiddle.net/v3cjG/2/ ) I get an error for "Can't find  variable calbck"--the var I said you were passing without defining.

Comment: no.. i have debugging turned off. Seems to be working except for the timeout part.

Comment: Why would you ask a question here without even bothering to debug first?